# asp.net MVC regularexpression validation for List of Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, list

I am facing issue with validating List of controls using regular expression custom validator in asp.net MVC 2.0.

My code is below. This uses custom validator. But this is not working, any suggestion? This is assigning error to all the controls if any one control value is invalid.

```
[QuestionRegularExpression(@"\d{2}", ErrorMessage = "Must be numeric")]
public List<IDateQuestion> DriverViolationsList { get; private set; }
    public ViolationDatesFormModel()
    {
        DriverViolationsList = new List<IDateQuestion>();
    }
```

this didn’t work. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume QuestionRegularExpression inherits from the regular expression validation attribute?  If so, I don't think this control can validate an object that's a list...

Comment: Correct QuestionRegularExpression inherits from the regular expression validation attribite.[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)] public sealed class QuestionRegularExpressionAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute { public QuestionRegularExpressionAttribute(string pattern) : base(pattern) { } public override bool IsValid(object value) { var question = value as IQuestion; return question == null || question.Value == null || base.IsValid(question.Value); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register the adapter on `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
        typeof(QuestionRegularExpressionAttribute),
        typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
}
```